# Why does my code output different results when using the if statement in a while loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop, range

In the while loop

When I use "if letter != guess" the "You Lose" works well but not the "You win"- it displays a reduction in lives_left and the ASCII art as loosing lives when it shouldn't

When I use "if letter not in chosen word" the "You win" works well but not the "You Lose"- it keeps looping to "guess a letter"

Please explain both cases and solution

```
import random

stages = ['''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 / \  |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 /    |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|   |
      |
      |
=========''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
  |   |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
      |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
      |
      |
      |
      |
=========
''']


word_list = ["cat"]
chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)

#Testing code
print(f'Pssst, the solution is {chosen_word}.\n')

chosen_word_list = []


lives_left = 6
print(f"You have {lives_left} lives to use\n")

for i in range(len(chosen_word)):
 chosen_word_list.append("_")

print(f"{chosen_word_list}\n")


game_end = False


while not game_end:
  
  
    
  guess = input("Guess a letter: \n\n").lower()
  

  for i in range(len(chosen_word)):
    letter = chosen_word[i]

    
    if letter == guess:
      chosen_word_list[i] = letter


      print(f"\n{chosen_word_list}")
      print(stages[6])


  
  if letter != guess:
    lives_left -= 1
    print(f"You have {lives_left} lives remaining\n")
    print(stages[lives_left])
    
    if lives_left == 0:
      game_end = True
      print("You lose")

  
  
    
  chosen_word_list_str = " ".join(chosen_word_list)
  chosen_word_replace_space = chosen_word_list_str.replace(" ","")
  # print(chosen_word_replace_space)

  
  if chosen_word == chosen_word_replace_space:
    game_end = True
    print("You win")
```

Comment: Immediately after `guess = input...`, you should have `if guess in chosen_word:`.  If it IS, then you can go ahead and replace the letters.  If NOT, then you know it was a miss.

Comment: sorry guys i found the problem  ....if letter != guess, the for loop iteration ends with "t", therefore always !=............and the other problem was using "letter" instead of "if guess in chosen word"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First problem: "if letter != guess"**

You keep cycling through the letters of chosen_word even after you found a match.
For the example "cat" if you choose 'a' then letter == guess is True for i = 1.

However the for loop keeps going and when you get to letter != guess the value of your letter is 't' instead of 'a'.

The fix is easy. Just add a break to the end of if letter == guess

```
for i in range(len(chosen_word)):
    letter = chosen_word[i]

    
    if letter == guess:
      chosen_word_list[i] = letter


      print(f"\n{chosen_word_list}")
      print(stages[6])
      break
```

Sorry but I did not understand what you were asking on the second problem.

Answer (score 2):

> When I use "if letter != guess" the "You Lose" works well but not the "You win"- it displays a reduction in lives_left and the ASCII art as loosing lives when it shouldn't

That's because at that moment `letter` is the last letter that was visited in the loop that had just been executed before this `if`. That makes no sense, and in most cases this expression will be true.

> When I use "if letter not in chosen word" the "You win" works well but not the "You Lose"- it keeps looping to "guess a letter"

That's because `letter` is the last letter in `chosen_word` (see above reasoning) and so this condition cannot be true.

You need to test `guess`, not `letter`. So:

```
    if guess not in chosen_word:
```

Comment: I support `if letter not in guess` for clarity, but for building up mental skills (and completeness), it might be good to mention that another way to solve this is to add a `break` in the `if letter == guess` that's inside the `while`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placing your condition inside the 'for' loop, check if the letter is in the `chosen_word` array (a string is also an array)

```
if guess in chosen_word:
  chosen_word_list[chosen_word.index(guess)] = guess
  print(f"\n{chosen_word_list}")
  print(stages[6])

else:
  lives_left -= 1
  print(f"You have {lives_left} lives remaining\n")
  print(stages[lives_left])
```

and it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

stages = ['''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 / \  |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 /    |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|   |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
  |   |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
      |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
      |
      |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
      |
      |
      |
      |
      |
=========
''']


#you can't have two same letters in one word
word_list = ["cat", "dog", "duck", "chair", "house", "sky", "nose", "brick", "car", "clothes", "sea"]
chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)

#Testing code
#print(f'Pssst, the solution is {chosen_word}.\n')

chosen_word_list = []


lives_left = len(stages)-1
print(f"You have {lives_left} lives to use\n")
print(stages[lives_left])

for i in range(len(chosen_word)):
 chosen_word_list.append("_")

print(f"\n{chosen_word_list}\n")


game_end = False


while not game_end:
  
  
    
  guess = input("Guess a letter: \n\n").lower()
  

  if guess in chosen_word:
    chosen_word_list[chosen_word.index(guess)] = guess
    print(f"\n{stages[lives_left]}")
    print(f"\n{chosen_word_list}\n")

  
  else:
    lives_left -= 1
    print(f"You have {lives_left} lives remaining\n")
    print(stages[lives_left])
    print(f"\n{chosen_word_list}\n")
    
    if lives_left == 0:
      game_end = True
      print(f"You lose\nthe word was {chosen_word}")

  
  
    
  chosen_word_list_str = " ".join(chosen_word_list)
  chosen_word_replace_space = chosen_word_list_str.replace(" ","")
  # print(chosen_word_replace_space)

  
  if chosen_word == chosen_word_replace_space:
    game_end = True
    print("You win")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).